# Lua and C-struct

Tags: c, lua

how can I use c-struct in lua?

Comment: Please clarify. You need to pass a data scructure from C to Lua?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to access fields in a C struct from Lua, set a userdata to the address of the C struct and set suitable metamethods to get and set fields.

Answer (score 3):

A terse question on a vast topic...
You can use, for example, the http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/struct/ library, made by one of the Lua authors. There are alternatives, including writing your own C code to interface with Lua, access or build the structure, etc.